# Show an exception message from a resharper plugin

Tags: visual-studio, resharper

In the course of the development of a Resharper plugin, I'd like to show an error message to a user when they incorrectly use a context action. Is there a way to pop up a window in Visual Studio to communicate the Resharper exception message to the user? I'm developing a plugin with Resharper 8 and VS 2012

Comment: What's wrong with just using `MessageBox.Show`? Or do you have requirements that make this approach unworkable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can always use `MessageBox` - ReSharper also provides a `MessageBox` static class that provides a number of helper methods to make it easy to display what you want. It also allows for adding "message box handlers" so that you don't actually display a message box during testing.

Alternatively, if you're creating a context action, and you're (indirectly) deriving from `BulbActionBase`, your `ExecutePsiTransaction` method (which should do all the work) can return an `Action<ITextControl>`. This allows you to return an action that will execute after the quick fix/context action has completed, which can be anything from positioning the caret, changing the selection, executing a template or showing a tooltip as an error.

You can return something like this:

```
return tc => myLocks.QueueReadLock("MyContextAction", () => {
    myTooltipManager.Show("Something went wrong!", 
      lifetime => new TextControlPopupWindowContext(lifetime, tc, myLocks, myActionManager);
  });
```

This is using a number of fields: `IShellLocks myLocks`, `ITooltipManager myTooltipManager` and `IActionManager myActionManager`. These can be injected into a component's constructor by ReSharper's component model, or you can get them with `solution.GetComponent<IShellLocks>`, etc.

What's happening is that you're returning an action that takes in an `ITextControl`, and which immediately queues up another action to run, on the UI thread, with the read lock taken. This second action tells the tooltip manager to show an error message as a tooltip, and provides a factory method for creating a popup window context (the `lifetime` parameter is created and disposed by the call to `Show`, and allows for cleanup of the context).

You could also look at the `ShowAtCaret` extension method to `ITooltipManager` - I can't remember offhand where `Show` will place the tooltip.